# My paging source always starts from my pageSize instead of 1

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-paging, android-paging-3

I need my start distance at first request to be 1 , then I need it to be 101 and then 201 and so on, my limit should always be 100, but I have tried everything in the PagingConfig and I cannot get this behavior , here are 2 images of what I get and the code below

### PagingSource

[image: Paging Source]

```
val page = params.key ?: 1
            val size = params.loadSize
            val from = page * size
            val data = homeRepository.getLatest(start = from, limit = size)
            val coinList = data.getOrNull()
```

### ViewModel

[image]

```
val coinList = Pager(
                pagingSourceFactory = { HomePagingSource(repo) },
                config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 100, prefetchDistance = 0, initialLoadSize = 100)
            ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with

```
  val coinList = Pager(
                pagingSourceFactory = { HomePagingSource(repo) },
                config = PagingConfig(
                    pageSize = NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE,
                    initialLoadSize = NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE,
                    prefetchDistance = 1
                )
            ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

and

```
const val NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE = 100
private const val INITIAL_LOAD_SIZE = 1

                val position = params.key ?: INITIAL_LOAD_SIZE
                val offset = if (params.key != null) ((position - 1) * NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE) + 1 else INITIAL_LOAD_SIZE
                val data = homeRepository.getLatest(start = offset, limit = params.loadSize)
                val coinList = data.getOrNull()
```